# Find the sum of the squares of all sides and diagonals of a n-gon inscribed in a circle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

With a circle with radius r and center A, for any homogenous n-gon -- find the sum of the squares of all sides and diagonals of the n-gon inscribed within the circle. I believe the general rule for the expressions is $ A_{n-1} A^2 _{n} $ , however I do not know how to calculate the sum. I believe using complex numbers will help.

Comment: Have you tried calculating that for $n=3,4,6$ and looked for a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i, 1\le i\le n$ be the roots on the complex plane of $x^n-1$.

We need to find the closed form of
$$
\sum_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j}).
$$

Hint: Vieta's theorem.

Let me finish this.
$$
2\sum_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)(\bar{x_i}-\bar{x_j})=\sum_{i, j}2-x_j\bar{x_i}-x_i\bar{x_j}\\
=\sum_{i,j}2-2x_i \bar{x_j}=\sum_{i,j}2-2\sum_{i}x_i\sum_{j} \bar{x_j}\\
=\sum_{i,j}2=2n^2.
$$

Comment: I tried something similar, I did the sum of modulus Z_n - Z_n-1 squared, would that be beneficial ?

Comment: How does the two come in ? @MaMing

Comment: @None For convenience sake. $2 \sum_{i<j}=\sum_{i,j}$.

Comment: I tried using the sum of the modulus Z_n - Z_n-1 squared, and I end up getting r^2n^2, where r is the radius of the circle. @MaMing

Comment: Your result coincides with mine, as I am unconsciously assuming $r=1$.@None

Comment: But, isn't your answer double mine ? @MaMing

Comment: @None NO. The multiplier "2" I added is only for convenience's sake, it should be divided out in the end.